# Cassandra read performance

Tags: cassandra

I want to know how to configure Cassandra to get better READ performances, because when I try to do a `SELECT` query on a table which has 1M rows I get the `timedoutexception`.

I've already change the `request_timeout_in_ms`, add more nodes but still got the same error.

Comment: Can you post your table schema and the query you are trying to make?  What is wrong will depend on how you are querying the table, and what the table looks like.

Comment: I have one table with 15 columns on my keyspace and i tied to make a select on one column :  select p0001 from eExtension limit 100000;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying too many rows at once.  You need to query less rows at a time and page through them.

**Update:**

First query:

```
select <KEY>,p0001 from eExtension limit 1000;
```

Repeat:
take the last result from that query:

```
select <KEY>,p0001 from eExtension where token(<KEY>) > token(<LAST KEY RETURNED FROM PREVIOUS>) limit 1000;
```

repeat that pattern until done.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it ??!!

Comment: First query:
select <KEY>,p0001 from eExtension limit 1000;
take the last result from that query:
select <KEY>,p0001 from eExtension where token(<KEY>) > token(<LAST KEY RETURNED FROM PREVIOUS>) limit 1000;
repeat that pattern until done.

Comment: Assume that I have a request like this :
Select p0002 from eExtension where e001= true ;
I don't really see how can I use the paging.

Comment: Works the same way. add token() > token().

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to read all 1M rows at once.  Don't.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do pagination is to use Cassandra's clients app like Playorm. PlayOrm returns a cursor when you query and as your first page reads in the first 100 results and displays it, the next page can just use the same cursor in your session and it picks up right where it left off without rescanning the first 100 rows again.
Visit [this](http://buffalosw.com/wiki/An-example-to-begin-with-PlayOrm/) to see the example for cursor and [this](http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/) for all features and more details about playorm